# Graph Model evaluation index error

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to learn Keras GraphNN using [simple examples](http://keras.io/models/). I have a simple example dataset with 784 features and I want to run this example:

```
 # graph model with one input and two outputs
    graph = Graph()
    graph.add_input(name='input', input_shape=(784,))
    graph.add_node(Dense(input_dim=784, output_dim=13), name='dense1', input='input')
    graph.add_node(Dense(input_dim=13, output_dim=1), name='dense2', input='input')
    graph.add_node(Dense(input_dim=13, output_dim=1), name='dense3', input='dense1')
    graph.add_output(name='output1', input='dense2')
    graph.add_output(name='output2', input='dense3')

    graph.compile('rmsprop', {'output1': 'mse', 'output2': 'mse'})
    graph.fit({'input': X_train, 'output1': y_train, 'output2': y_train}, nb_epoch=30)
### here is where I am facing difficulty
    score = graph.evaluate({'input': X_test, 'output1': y_test, 'output2': y_test}, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
    print 'score: ', score
```

The documentation mentions that `graph.evaluate()`:

> **evaluate**(data, batch_size=128, verbose=1): Show performance of the model over some validation data.
>   **Return**: The loss score over the data.
>   **Arguments**: Same meaning as fit method above. verbose is used as a binary flag (progress bar or nothing).

And from the definition of the `graph.fit()` we know that:

> **Arguments**:
>   **data**:dictionary mapping input names out outputs names to appropriate numpy arrays. All arrays should contain the same number of samples.

Although my fit method runs perfect, I get `IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for size 1` on `evaluate`

My input shapes are:

```
Xtrain:  (32738, 784)
Xtest:  (16125, 784)
ytest:  (16125,)
ytrain:  (32738,)
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: full error stack trace would be very helpful.

Comment: is your data pandas data frames or numpy arrays?  Keras only take numpy arrays so convert them and you should be good.